Standard link relation for adding items to collection?
  Relation Name:

      item
 
   Description:

      The target IRI points to a resource that is a member of the
      collection represented by the context IRI.


   Relation Name:

      collection

   Description:

      The target IRI points to a resource that represents the collection
      resource for the context IRI.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6573.html
Why isn't there a standard relation for adding items to a collection? Am I missing something?
